# Mapping Relationships between a JPA model and A MongoDb model class in a Spring Boot Project

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, nosql

I have 3 classes as **user**, **blog** and **like** in a Spring Boot Project.User and Blog classes have **JPA MySQL relational DB** model and for Like class I'm using **MongoDB non relational** model.How to map relationships between those  3 classes?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using a different datastore for `Like` than for the other entities. JPA can't possibly help you with maintaining relationships between those entities. The only solution I see is for `Like` to have a `postId` property (with sth like `PostFacade` service to save and retrieve `Like`s using the id of a given `Post`)

Comment: Now I'm using user:blog 1:M bidirectional relationship.For like mongoDB model I have  private Long blog_id; and  private Long user_id.But when I have private List<Like>likes=new ArrayList<>() in blog JPA model it gives an error.What's the reason?

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my comment. There **cannot exist** a direct association between `Blog` and `Like`. You need to manage the relationship some other way, hence my suggestion with the facade. You could mark `likes` as `@Transient`, but you still need to manage retrieving and updating the list without the help of JPA